# Payment information API returns 400 error

Tags: error, api, magento2.3, rest-api

Link `http://protectcovers.ga/rest/store_view_eu/V1/guest-carts/ddukH6HL2TlFsm9WkJmOkMDSqmkiUfbW/payment-information`

I tried to send the next json:

`{
    "cartId": "ddukH6HL2TlFsm9WkJmOkMDSqmkiUfbW",
    "billingAddress": {
        "countryId": "CA",
        "regionId": "71",
        "regionCode": "NS",
        "region": "Nova Scotia",
        "street": ["Test street 113"],
        "company": "Test",
        "telephone": "0123456789",
        "postcode": "123456",
        "city": "Test",
        "firstname": "Test",
        "lastname": "Test",
        "saveInAddressBook": null
    },
    "paymentMethod": {
        "method": "mollie_methods_paypal"
    },
    "email": "consumer@ciasd.asd"
}`

And it returns the next error:

```
{
    "message": "An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.",
    "trace": "#0 /var/www/html/protectcovers.ml/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\GuestPaymentInformationManagement->savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder('ddukH6HL2TlFsm9...', 'consumer@ciasd....', Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Payment), Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Address))\n#1 /var/www/html/protectcovers.ml/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\GuestPaymentInformationManagement\\Interceptor->___callParent('savePaymentInfo...', Array)\n#2 /var/www/html/protectcovers.ml/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\GuestPaymentInformationManagement\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}('ddukH6HL2TlFsm9...', 'consumer@ciasd....', Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Payment), Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Address))\n#3 /var/www/html/protectcovers.ml/generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/GuestPaymentInformationManagement/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\GuestPaymentInformationManagement\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('savePaymentInfo...', Array, Array)\n#4 [internal function]: Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\GuestPaymentInformationManagement\\Interceptor->savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder('ddukH6HL2TlFsm9...', 'consumer@ciasd....', Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Payment), Object(Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Address))\n#5 /var/www/html/protectcovers.ml/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(95): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#6 /var/www/html/protectcovers.ml/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(188): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\SynchronousRequestProcessor->process(Object(Magento\\Framework\\Webapi\\Rest\\Request\\Proxy))\n#7 /var/www/html/protectcovers.ml/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#8 /var/www/html/protectcovers.ml/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n#9 /var/www/html/protectcovers.ml/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#10 /var/www/html/protectcovers.ml/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)\n#11 /var/www/html/protectcovers.ml/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(136): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#12 /var/www/html/protectcovers.ml/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#13 /var/www/html/protectcovers.ml/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->___callParent('launch', Array)\n#14 /var/www/html/protectcovers.ml/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}()\n#15 /var/www/html/protectcovers.ml/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('launch', Array, Array)\n#16 /var/www/html/protectcovers.ml/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch()\n#17 /var/www/html/protectcovers.ml/pub/index.php(39): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#18 {main}"
}
```

You can check it on the postman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue at  `Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement.php`

and Method `savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder` has some critical issue.

For debug this issue,Change the

```
throw new CouldNotSaveException(
                    __('An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.'),
                    $e
                );
```

**to**

```
throw new CouldNotSaveException(
                    __('An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.'.$e->getMessage()),
                    $e
                );
```

Also, check the exceptio.log you will find the reason of this error.